# json_encode a MySQL query for a multi-series flot chart

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, flot

I'm trying to pass a MySQL query to flot chart in the json format specified in the documentation i.e

```
[ { label: "Foo", data: [ [10, 1], [17, -14], [30, 5] ] },
  { label: "Bar", data: [ [11, 13], [19, 11], [30, -7] ] }
]
```

This is my current code:

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL and select database.

    require_once 'php/db_login.php';

    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
        if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($db_database)
        or die("Unable to select: ". mysql_error()); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Total,CCGT FROM generation ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 13");


while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $dataset1['label']= 'Total';
    $dataset1['data'] = array($row['ID'],$row['Total'],$row['CCGT']);
}

echo json_encode($dataset1);
```

Which returns:

```
{"label":"Total","data":["494","38431","12"]}
```

This is obviously wrong as it's in the wrong format and it only iterates though 1 result instead of 13. I've tried multiple code examples online but none of them produce the JSON format I'm looking for. All help gratefully received.

Comment: please check your json http://jsonlint.com/ there is an error

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataset1 = array()
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $d = array();
    $d['label']= 'Total';
    $d['data'] = array((int)$row['ID'],(int)$row['Total'],(int)$row['CCGT']);

    $dataset1[] = (object)$d;
}
```

I see, are you looking for this? updated

```
$dataset1 = array('label'=>'Total','data'=>array());
$dataset2 = array('label'=>'CCGT','data'=>array());
$d = &$dataset1['data'];
$d2 = &$dataset2['data'];
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{        
    $d[] = array((int)$row['ID'],(int)$row['Total']);
    $d2[] = array((int)$row['ID'],(int)$row['CCGT']);       
}
json_encode(array($dataset1,$dataset2));
```

Comment: Is this 1 series with 13 data points 3 value at each, or 13 series (labeld with id) 3 data points each?